# ruby split string into multiple strings of fixed length

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I was wondering if it was possible to split a string into multiple partitions of various lengths. I would like to split this string for example:

```
string = "1 name lastname       234   washington city/NY"
```

into four sub-strings, where:

- 1st partition to have 1st 2 characters (`"1 "`)
- 2nd partition to
  have subsequent 15 characters (`"name lastname            "`)
- 3rd partition
  to have subsequent 6 characters (`"234   "`)
- 4rd partition to have
  subsequent 20 characters (`"washington city/NY"`)

Comment: Please show us your real string(s) and what you want to do.

Comment: Show us the code you've written as you've attempted to solve this for yourself. As is it looks like you're asking us to write it for you. "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)"

Comment: up above is the real string actually :)

Comment: Dear @Tin Man, thank you very much for you long and useless message. Just because I dint show any work does not give you right to assume that I didnt work on solution to this problem prior to posting. I just didnt even understand how to approach this problem since I've never used regexes with so many criteria. You could probably see that I've already accepted answer from a nice fellow, who spent probably 30 seconds typing answer to my question. it's easy to help people who want to learn , isnt it?

Comment: Dear user2925006.  Please calm down and don't take Tin Man's comment personally.  He's just basically letting you know the rules as detailed in the FAQ's.  Please refrain from rants until you have the respect of the community as shown by your reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you do this simply by indexing:

```
string[0,2]
string[4,15]
stirng[20,6]
string[27,20]
```

Comment: God bless you! didnt know you could do it this way. thought I had to either use scan or split methods, and didnt know how to combine regular expression

Comment: Just remember that it will not work for 2345   washington city/NY

Answer (score 0):

Writing a `Regexp` isn't that hard. The [*free-spacing* mode](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html#label-Free-Spacing+Mode+and+Comments) lets you write the pattern on multiple lines and supports comments. Here's an example with named captures groups:

```
string = "1 name lastname       234   washington city/NY"

pattern = /\A
  (?<id>.{2})    # 2 charcters for the id
  (?<name>.{20}) # 20 characters for the name
  (?<zip>.{6})   # 6 characters for the zip code
  (?<city>.+)    # remaining characters for city and state
\Z/x

match = string.match(pattern)
#=> #<MatchData "1 name lastname       234   washington city/NY" id:"1 " name:"name lastname       " zip:"234   " city:"washington city/NY">

match[:id]   #=> "1 "
match[:name] #=> "name lastname       "
match[:zip]  #=> "234   "
match[:city] #=> "washington city/NY"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helps even more!